# QtSQL how to read record as QMap

Tags: qt4, qtsql

is there a quick way to read record from query as a `QMap<QString,QVariant>` or similar type ?

Or maybe You could tell me how to access the list of columns in current record ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such method. But You can construct QMap object containing all columns like this:

```
QString sql = "SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE id = x";
query.exec(sql);
QSqlRecord record = query.record();
query.next();

QMap<QString,QVariant> params;
for (int i=0; i<record.count(); ++i) {
    params.insert(record.fieldName(i++), query.value(i));
}
```

As you can see QSqlRecord provides access to information about columns and so on.